# Is this a mistake in the definition of the sign bit for integer types in the C standard?

Tags: c, standards, language-lawyer

I think there's an error describing the sign bit for integer types in section 6.2.6.2 of the [ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall
>   be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign
>   bit. There need not be any padding bits; there shall be exactly one
>   sign bit. Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as
>   the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding
>   unsigned type (if there are M value bits in the signed type and N in
>   the unsigned type, then M ≤ N). If the sign bit is zero, it shall not
>   affect the resulting value. If the sign bit is one, the value shall be
>   modified in one of the following ways:
>
> - the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);
> - the sign bit has the value −(2^N) (two’s complement);
> - the sign bit has the value −(2^N − 1) (ones’ complement)

In the previous section, N was defined to be the number of value bits in the signed type, but here it's the number of value bits in the *unsigned* type.

Taking the case of `signed char` with 8 bits per byte and two's complement, this is saying that the sign bit has value -(2^8) =-256 rather than -(2^7) = -128.

I think the standard should either switch M and N in the initial paragraph or change the definition of the sign bit to use M:

> - the sign bit has the value −(2^M) (two’s complement);
> - the sign bit has the value −(2^M − 1) (ones’ complement)

Did I miss something, or is this an error?

Comment: The most charitable (and probably correct, as far as intent is concerned) interpretation is probably that the first definition of *N* in paragraph 1 is meant to apply to the whole section, *except* for the parenthetical remark in paragraph 2, where *N* (and *M*) is temporarily given a different definition. But yes, it's somewhat ambiguous at best. Blame it on English having such poor variable scoping rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [C11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)(*Jonathan Leffler confirms the final standard also contains this wording*) it does indeed switch from using `N` to using `M`:

> - the sign bit has the value −(2<sup>M</sup>) (two’s complement);
> - the sign bit has the value −(2<sup>M</sup> − 1) (ones’ complement).

I can not find a defect report but this hinges on whether:

> If there are N value bits

from paragraph `1` also applies to paragraph `2` which is not an unreasonable interpretation it is just highly ambiguous given:

> (if there are
>   M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M <= N)

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. But I think only us programmers could think that the second definition of N shadows the first only inside the parens :)

Comment: The final C11 standard uses -(2^M) and -(2^M-1) too.